# Beautiful Soup - Class contains 'a' and not contains 'b'

Tags: python-2.7, beautifulsoup

Using `bs4` I need to find an element with `class_=re.compile("viewLicense")` but not `class_="viewLicenseDetails"`

Here is the snippet,

```
<tr class="viewLicense inactive"></tr>
<tr class="viewLicense"></tr>
<tr id="licenseDetails_552738" class="viewLicenseDetails"</tr>
```

I want the first two tr and not want the last one.

Could someone please help, Thanks

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Following will find every `tr` tag with viewLicense

```
soup.find_all("tr", class_="viewLicense")
```

So, it will work for the text provided in quesiton:

```
>>> soup.find_all("tr", class_="viewLicense")
[<tr class="viewLicense inactive"></tr>, <tr class="viewLicense"></tr>]
```

However if you have a `tr` tag which has both `viewLicense` and `viewLicenseDetails` classes, then following will find all `tr` tags with `viewLicense` and then remove tags with `viewLicenseDetails`:

```
>>> both_tags = soup.find_all("tr", class_="viewLicense")
>>> for tag in both_tags:
...     if 'viewLicenseDetails' not in tag.attrs['class']:
...             print tag
```

Answer (score 4):

Use CSS selectors?

```
results = soup.select('tr.viewLicense')
```